# Offset Index Charting

Tags: python, charts, timeserieschart

I am trying to plot two stock prices on an index plot. This plot is very common as it starts both stocks with different prices, at the same place.

See below for a chart of IBM vs. TSLA

```
def get_historical_closes(ticker, start_date, end_date):
    # get the data for the tickers.  This will be a panel
    p = wb.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", start_date, end_date)
    # convert the panel to a DataFrame and selection only Adj Close
    # while making all index levels columns
    d = p.to_frame()['Adj Close'].reset_index()
    # rename the columns
    d.rename(columns={'minor': 'Ticker', 'Adj Close': 'Close'}, inplace=True)
    # pivot each ticker to a column
    pivoted = d.pivot(index='Date', columns='Ticker')
    # and drop the one level on the columns
    pivoted.columns = pivoted.columns.droplevel(0)
    return pivoted

tickers = ['IBM','TSLA']
start   = '2015-12-31'
end     ='2016-12-22'

df_ret=get_historical_closes(tickers,start,end).pct_change().replace('NaN',0)
df_ret=np.cumprod(1+df_ret)
df_ret.plot()
```

As you can see, both start at 1.00.

What I would like to do is to have the convergence at 1.00 be at some arbitrary point in the date index. For example, I would like to see the same chart, except that the lines converge at 1 on July 31, 2016. Thus, offsetting the index convergence at a given point.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to make it more difficult than what it actually should be. See below:

```
            df_day=df_ret[df_ret.index=='2016-03-31']

            df_plot = pd.DataFrame(index=df_ret.index, columns=df_ret.columns)

            for col in df_ret.columns:        # For each factor
                df_plot[col]=df_ret[col]/df_day[col].values

            df_plot.plot()
```